# Calculate harmonic series from an audio --Python

Tags: python, audio, librosa

I am wondering if there's any way to calculate harmonic series from an audio, because I want to calculate the **brightness**.

For example, I want the sum of `(100*1 + 200*2 + 400*4...)`

[image].

I am thinking of something like this.
Load audio from librosa first, then get the `y` from the `(y, sr) = librosa.load(audio file).` 
But I have no idea how to calculate harmonic series in Python.
By the way, there is some uncertainty about how to do the sum.

----- **Edit**

This is from a paper talking about a model called [MIDI-DDSP](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2112.09312).
Here is the section I can't understand.

> Brightness is defined as the spectral centroid (in bin numbers) of the harmonic distribution,
> where hk(i) represents the k-th bin of the harmonic distribution, h(τ) in the i-th time-step, and we use |h| to refer to the number of bins in the harmonic distribution used by the DDSP module (we use |h| = 60, see Appendix B.2).

Hope someone can help me, and give me suggestion.

Comment: What exactly do you want to calculate? The fundamental tone (first harmonic) in the audio?

Comment: Yes! The fundamental tone, I edit something in my question.

Comment: I don't think we have enough to get you a useable answer. Usually with harmonics, it's in the form of a summation of 1/freqs in the harmonics. So this seems odd but not impossible. But there is no code, no link to the paper, and no format for the data. Could you clarify a bit?

Comment: okay, I'll paste the paper link. As for the data and code, I think it's just audio, any of an audio. I thought there'd have some tools to calculate the harmonic series.

Comment: MIDI-DDSP refers to synthesis, where the fundamental f0 is known/set. Are you analyzing audio and need to estimate f0?

Comment: Spectral centroid measured in frequency (or fixed bins from FFT, mel or chroma scale) is a common metric for brightness, and has an implementation in `librosa.features.spectral_centroid`

Comment: Yes, I want to analyze the audio. Oh, so I don't need to calculate the fundamental f0 if I implement this model?

Comment: @JonNordby, nice! Thanks to Librosa. Then, I want to check if I understand it in the right way or not. 
After I input an audio, the **cent from these codes ```y, sr = librosa.load(librosa.ex('trumpet'))
cent = librosa.feature.spectral_centroid(y=y, sr=sr)``` would output the frequency. Am I right?

Comment: Yes that sounds about right. If you get it working, you should make an answer here with minimal code example. Then you can mark it as "accepted"